# How to choose the right selenium reporting tool?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, reporting

I'd like to add reporting to Selenium tests, and am at a loss to decide which tool to choose.
there's the TestNG -> ReportNG, extent and Extent report, Allure, and perhaps others.

My priorities are:

1. open source  (I believe all are, please correct me if I'm wrong)
2. larger user base (or high adoption rate compared to other alternatives)
3. Quality/beauty of visual result

(If other factors are important, I'd be happy to edit the question accordingly)

Many thanks,
Dror

Comment: All open source. Allure largest user base. Extent is new,  easy to use and customize,  best looking by far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ATU Reporter for Selenium TestNG

to display test case status - Pass Fail, attach screenshots, etc.

http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/p/reporting.html

Comment: Would you recommend atu over allure/extent?